# Reimport a SubReport into Crystal Reports Java

Tags: java, crystal-reports-2008

My Requirement:

- I have a SubReport which is suppose to work as a header of all other reports.
- Any change in this header report should be directly displayed in other reports
  . The header template contains only some information like name & logo.

What i did:

- Created a subreport as per myrequirement
- Inserted it into my Main report
- selected the option of "Re-import while opening".

Problem:

- It doesn't work as i thought.
- Every time i do some changes in my header report, i need to manually re - import the subreport.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with CR.

The automatic import does not work at all. Working with the model (at least in CR XI.5) didn't work also, but they might have worked on it in 2008.

Reworking the reports in Java was very slow also. I take the resulting report now, and use a Java PDF library to overlay the report over an PDF (also makes watermarks etc. easy), and have removed all subreports.

I will definitely switch to Jasper Reports when I get the time to do so, because I noticed that working with CR is a pain in the a**.

Comment: Thanks for the ans.:) No it doesn't work, i tried it in both CR X1 as well as in CR 2008 Evaluation version. but no luck :(( BTW what java lib r u using, is it IText ?

Answer (score 0):

Although this has already been answered - I'm chiming in because this confirmed what I had found.
Using Crystal Reports Version 11.0.0.1282 - The Re-Import When Opening doesn't seem to work as advertised.  I have to manually touch each Main report and re-import the SubReport to get any changes reflected.

I am not amused.